# Typescript pulling return type from function interfaces and having issue with pickup wrong type

Tags: typescript, function, types, parameters, extract

I'm try to extract types from function interface.

```js
...
...
...

type EdmSchemaValue<T> = {
    type: EdmMap<T>;
    nullable?: boolean;
};

type EdmSchema<T> = {[K in keyof T]: T extends object ? EdmSchemaValue<T[K]> : never};

type EdmFunctionSchema<T extends FunctionWithAgs, RT = UnPromisify<ReturnType<T>>> = {
    params: EdmParameterArray<T>;
    returnType: EdmMap<RT> | EdmSchema<RT>;
};

const hostDataSchema: EdmSchema<IHostEntry> = {
    address: {type: Edm.String, nullable: false},
    hostname: {type: Edm.String, nullable: false},
    aliases: {type: [Edm.String], nullable: false},
};

interface IFunc {
    list(all: string): Promise<IHostEntry[]>;
}

const functionSchema: EdmFunctionObject<IFunc> = {
    list: {params: [{type: Edm.String, name: 'all', nullable: false}], returnType: [hostDataSchema]},
};
```

I think most of this is ok, but I'm getting "hostDataSchema" `const hostDataSchema: EdmSchema<IHostEntry> Property 'type' is missing in type 'EdmSchema<IHostEntry>' but required in type 'EdmSchemaValue<IHostEntry>`

For this returnType gives `(property) returnType: never[] | EdmSchemaValue<IHostEntry>[]` which is wrong but I can't figure why as it should be visible either as EdmMap or EdmSchema

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgrgOwMbAJYHsEHVXABYCCA5gM5QC8UAFAHR0CGATqQFxT0IgCUFAfO5wDcAKFCQoAVQQAFRugC2qEqgBmIADwAVfpU1QIAD2AQEAEzKyFSiOtQIVERpP4B+SVDaaRwk3HlQAUVN-AG9hAEgAZWBGOyIKKAByIPkaaNiEIkSAGgiAOT8AI0cE5OCaAvlixhzhAF9RcGgUgFl6MEi4gBsbbQS9Q2MzMhIYuKg3FLSxzI8oAaMTcygEIpLJ8srquYQIADdHETFm4LawAkZGeg0FoeWLq40OEF4dKBCAbQBpKDsoAGsICB0Cp5gBdNitdqdTI9LTfMG8OpHJqBU7tLRvW5LMgPa7qZ6uNHyM54m78SHojrdXq8bzHYmRJB4CDyegANXoXTgtISYXCx0pJIx2hE4VWXS69EKPRcbEK6HQPQ4ImRwka4hS0iY9HkEGMjE53N62SgeQSowyRDe-MFxLOmLFCF1EDYeSdcEl0tl8sVyoQqvpqJSTJZbMxfO+vwQAKBIPBnn0i2GUHQhQAVhAUBNGczWRyuTz4V9ETt9o41QytTq9QatEm7mQ05mUDao39AcDQZoIcTtVda44jUXNAikSjNcF+y6DWT64McbBECgMNhcIRSKbpAQEtPB4wSJi2z8O3HQdve9WB-qh4WbNux5Xg8F4Mg0JhQ-n58nlq+V5gcHwYgSFNAAlPRKCkSxFGUNR1FA-U4EYBBNCaI8bQiMAaxIIU9xvRg51FCJGEQ5DUMgIUHXA-gAB9czDeh4KIp9J3kP93wQAB5DMs2Ab9G1THjW0jE8Y07eMe08BEG0XdjV0AjcyA2Njlw4z9w1HEsKRWctGDVYQ7ANFR6CQaAAEkAAl0FGAIEBiEB3giehTFMEiSBwqBLTiMU8Gs4BnT1NgvMyMUuVQegSAgDzgqID4wVVdUkEwUYoF80YABF6GAeh1PoIVcvUSy-Ns+yMPCZzXKijyQjtKZ0jiU0JSlGVXSgYyukiupcnCNL-JdNgaqaIVpitRrPWano2HazrurCiKooGu0PjqmYiDBMavRaqauRm+pvEMxxjNMqAzL-Rzwi6JRgCoLkuiC1auDYaDrEKqybLsxgQDiul6kS5LgDa1TV1yoU5MwbiWz407lzKy7RgGrCBw8j5Boo4kRoalZ+qSW6chWcbvVa6aIDqdaoBI4AkJQoaoA+XrMuy3KwS6vbhCAA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mistake in one of your types:

```
type EdmFunctionSchema<T extends FunctionWithAgs, RT = UnPromisify<ReturnType<T>>> = {
    params: EdmParameterArray<T>;
    returnType: EdmMap<RT> | EdmSchema<RT>;
};
```

should be

```
type EdmFunctionSchema<T extends FunctionWithAgs, RT = UnPromisify<ReturnType<T>>> = {
    params: EdmParameterArray<T>;
    returnType: EdmMap<RT> | EdmSchema<T>; // here
};
```